# How is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{-16}} = -\frac{1}{4}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, solution-verification

> Simplify $(-16)^{ -\frac{1}{2}}$

Here is my attempt at solving this question:

\begin{align}
(-16)^{ -\frac{1}{2} } &= \frac{1}{(-16)^\frac{1}{2}} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{-16}}
\end{align}

$$ \therefore \text{The answer is undefined} $$

This was the answer:

\begin{align}
(-16)^{ -\frac{1}{2} } &= \left( \frac{1}{-16} \right) ^\frac{1}{2} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{-16}} \\
&= -\frac{1}{4}
\end{align}

Isn't $\sqrt{-16}$ invalid? How can $\frac{1}{\sqrt{-16}}$ be simplified to $-\frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: the answer $-{1\over4}$ is incorrect. The (principle) answer would be $i\over 4$, but if you are only considering real numbers, then you are correct that this isn't defined.

Comment: Which textbook? Try to get your money back.

Comment: The titular equality is false. LHS is imaginary, whereas RHS is real.

Comment: Are you sure it is $(-16)^{-1/2}$ and not $-16^{-1/2}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you disallow imaginary numbers, it is undefined.  Otherwise, there are two solutions to $x^2=-1/16$, namely $$\pm\frac{1}{4i}=\pm\frac{i}{4},$$ where $i=\sqrt{-1}$.  In any case, it is not $-1/4$.

Comment: Are you sure? Where $-\frac{i}{4}$? Also, are you sure that $\sqrt{-1}=i$?

Comment: That depends on how you define the square root function. If there are two results, then it is not simply a function.

Comment: Yes, corrected.